# Ethereum applications with off-chain business logic

Tags: dapps, off-chain

I am looking for real-world applications using Ethereum Smart Contracts that include complex off-chain business logic. I could find several useful examples of DApps, however, the off-chain layer often consists of a simple user interface.

I need some real examples where the off-chain layer has other functionalities than simply rendering the results of the transactions or storing data.

Please add any resource that you think would be useful. Many thanks!

Comment: There is no difference between a "classic" program logic and what you call "off-chain layer". Just develop the logic you need.

Comment: @Itération122442 Thank you, I'm aware that there is no real difference between a classic program and the "off-chain" logic. Do you have any real example of such applications? I don't need to develop it, I just need some examples for testing purposes

Answer (score 0):

Some examples:

[Synthetix](https://synthetix.io/) is a synthetic asset marketplace that is using off-chain data like forex currency exchange rates.

[image]

[Crabada is a video game with NFTs](https://www.crabada.com/). It has now moved to its own Avalanche subnet due to high transaction volume.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As Mikko has stated there are Oracles off-chain that smart contracts fetch data from like Currency exchanges, and other real-time data to perform certain executions. These would come under the off-chain layer.